# Android SDK Tools Wizard: Detects JDK 1.7 instead of JDK 1.6

Tags: android, sdk

I am trying my hands on Android first time ever, so request you to pardon me if I sound too naive. I read on the ADT system requirements that it needs JDK 1.6 and also some of the tutorials it was said that ADT doesn't support JDK 1.7 yet.

I have both JDK 1.7 and JDK 1.6 ( also the JREs ) on my machine and I have set the JAVA_HOME to JDK 1.6. I tested by typing java -version and it shows me pointed to Java 1.6.

[image: Java Version]

However, when I run the Android SDK Tools Wizard it detects JDK 1.7 instead of 1.6. I am not sure if continuing with JDK 1.7 would lead to future problems during development.

[image: Android SDK Tools Wizard]

Please advise if this fine. Else, please suggest how can I correctly get this pointed to JDK 1.6. Note: I don't want to uninstall 1.7 as I need it for other development activities.

Comment: You may try this, (1) close the setup, (2) rename your jre7_21 to some other name(3) re-run the setup. (4) Once setup is completed again rename jre , back to jre7_21. This is not a perfect solution, but it worked. Take it as an advise, not a solution.

Comment: Thank you Kedarnath. Appreciate your time in responding. I will give  a try.

Comment: It seems, I found the reason why it's picking 1.7. It seems to be reading from the regedit ( on Windows ) i.e HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE variable. I changed the variable value there from 1.7 to 1.6 and it started picking up 1.6. Thank you :)

Comment: Good. Looks like I learn something new as well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> also some of the tutorials it was said that ADT doesn't support JDK 1.7 yet

ADT supports Java 1.7 (a.k.a., Java 7).

> I tested by typing java -version and it shows me pointed to Java 1.6

Note that this is testing the runtime environment, not the development environment. Use `javac -version` to test what version of the Java compiler you are using.

> I am not sure if continuing with JDK 1.7 would lead to future problems during development

That should be fine. I have been using Java 7 for the past 5-6 months without issue, albeit on Linux rather than Windows.

Comment: Thank You !!
While I found how to fix the version thing, your answer has given me some relief indeed. If ADT supports 1.7 perfectly fine, though mine is Windows unlike your's, I would like to give a try. If it works then I don't have to keep juggling between my java versions. Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

Here is answer to my question:

It seems the wizard was reading the JDK and JRE environment values from the Registry ( on Windows ) i.e HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE variable. I changed the variable values there from 1.7 to 1.6 and it started picking up 1.6